# Python Executables on Windows

Tags: python, windows-10

I just upgraded to windows 10, and downloaded the Anaconda Python distribution and chose the option for it to add everything to my PATH etc. Back in windows 8 when I created a .py file I could execute it from the file explorer just by clicking on it, but for some reason windows 10 won't recognise .py files and when I try run them it opens them in notepad. I am able to run them from the command line. What's gone wrong?

UPDATE: When I choose another application to open the file, I click on the python application and it says "Cannot Execute as Python27.dll is not found", I installed python 3, why is it trying to open in python2.7?

Comment: its called file associations ... right click a .py file and say "open with ..." and then select python  ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley python isn't an option...

Comment: it is you just have to "choose an executable" using the button that says "browse" at the bottom of the page where you would expect python to be

Answer (score 0):

Choose open with, then scroll down and click something like "choose another application from this computer" (I don't exactly know, I use windows in different language). Then just select your Python executable and click OK.

Comment: When I do this it says "Cannot execute as python27.dll is not installed", I installed python3 so I have no idea why it is looking for a python 2.7 thing..

Comment: What executable, did use exactly use?

Comment: I clicked "select another application to run this file", went to where python is installed, and clicked on the icon that said "python" and was labeled as an application type